# What causes metallic tastes when you receive electric shocks

Tags: human-physiology, taste, electrical-stimulation

Whenever I receive small electric charges (most often by, e.g. touching the jack of a plugged in charging cable, or the casing of a charging Apple device), I experience a very distinctive taste in my mouth.

I'm relatively certain that the taste is what is termed "a metallic taste", and some brief googling suggests that this is a common experience when receiving an electric shock.

What is going on, biochemically, in this experience?

---

FWIW, it's the same sensory experience that I associate with a sudden physical danger shock, such as times when I've been standing on a branch that then broke (I was holding another branch, so was fine, but had a huge fear/adrenaline rush, plus that same metallic taste).
Are they linked experiences at all?

Comment: I think adding more support for your metallic taste sensation would add a lot of body to the question. As of now you seem to be asking the community to explain an anecdotal personal observation. Sensation and perception are subjective phenomena and personal anecdotes are not a very solid basis for a scientific question. I can list a quite a few sensations I have repeatedly perceived under various circumstances, yet I hardly find them to be solid enough to raise a question about.